# React JS: console.debug is not a function

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm running a ReactJs web app, my web running well in webpack-dev-server,
but chrome/firefox console always got "Uncaught TypeError: console.debug is not a function" after I bundle my codes, I have no idea how to solve this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what happens if you use console.log(...) instead of console.debug(..)?

Comment: No, I don't use console.debug, it seems from ReactJS or webpack, I don't know where is the source.

Comment: try adding debug: true in your webpack config file? Apparently console.debug(..) is not enabled by default since all browsers do not have it.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I add "node:{ console:true}",that solve my problem, thanks for your help

Comment: Also console.debug exists in both chrome and firefox.. try putting it in your console ;)

Comment: If you've solved it, you could put the solution in an answer to this question to help anyone else who may trip over this problem and come here.

Answer (score 2):

try adding `node: { console: true }` and `debug: true` in webpack config file.